# What are the implications of using an unsupported WebKit property?

Tags: ios, css, webkit

I am interested in using `-webkit-line-clamp` in a hybrid iOS app.

I have read the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-UnsupportedProperties) on the unsupported property.

Is it wise to use unsupported properties or am I risking removal of the feature in future implementations of webkit within mobile safari and other browser implementations?

How do I check on the status of WebKit properties?

Comment: Is there a better resource for information on that property?  The provided link doesn't mention the property at all.

Comment: @cimmanon, the linked page *mentions* the property; it just isn’t described at all, just characterized as “unsupported”.

Comment: The description of webkit-line-clamp is not as relevant as to what are future downsides to using any unsupported property now.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the design is still accessible to browsers that lack support for `-webkit-line-clamp` (ala `border-radius`), there are no implications to speak of.

Have browsers changed their implementation or dropped support of experimental properties in the past?  Sure.

- Safari's original implementation for gradients is quite different than the current standard
- WebKit browsers still support the prefixed `column-break-before` property, which was renamed to `break-before` in the current standard
- WebKit browsers still support properties from the 2009 Flexbox draft, despite being completely overhauled in late 2012

Thankfully, you can write your CSS in a way that works in browsers who support the old and the new implementations:

```
.foo {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
}
```

In the future, we'll have access to *feature queries* to detect whether or not a browser supports the specific properties (Opera supports it now, Firefox will have it *soon*:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries)

```
@supports not (-webkit-line-clamp: somevalue) {
    // some styles for unsupported browsers
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Chris Coyer wrote an article about this topic: http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/ And FTLabs creates a JS-Plugin for this: [FTEllipsis](https://github.com/ftlabs/ftellipsis) They use it for the new Financial Times iPad webapp - have a look at http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/23/building-the-new-financial-times-web-app/

Comment: very useful comment, it sort of answers my question of how future proof css line clamp is by creating a javascript solution. Good link!